# Why is it so hard to extract vector graphics from PDF?

Tags: python, pdf, data-mining, vector-graphics, postscript

There are many tools to extract raster graphics from PDF files like pdfimages.
Raster graphics are defined a dictionary of type XObject with subtype Image, a filter and a stream with the data. This makes is understandably easy to extract.

From my understanding vector graphics (SVG etc.) are stored in a dictionary XObject with subtype Form which contains a stream with operators like

```
stream
0 0 1 rg % set the color to blue in RGB
0 0 100 100 re % draw a rectangle 100x100 with the bottom left at 0,0
F % fill it
endstream
```

Still there are no out of the box tools to extract vector graphics **fully** automatically (e.g. python).

Where exactly is the technical difficulty?
What other things might be stored as "Form" objects which makes them hard to be distinguishable from vector graphics?

Comment: streams are compressed, you won't find such data in this state. to uncompress a PDF, you can use pdftk or anything.

Comment: *"From my understanding vector graphics (SVG etc.) are stored in a dictionary XObject with subtype Form"* - in my experience having a separate Form XObjects for each vector graphics figure is the exception. More often than not I see the drawing instructions for the whole page content - text, figures, whatnot, ... - in the page content streams with no indication where a specific figure starts and ends, where there is the main textual content, where there are pagination artifacts, etc. For tagged PDFs the situation is better, though.

Comment: Your intuition about Form XObjects is somewhat wrong. Form XObjects are indeed sometimes used by some PDF-producing programs to include external illustrations amongst some text, but this is mostly for convenience. There is no reason the content should not all be together in the main content stream. The real purpose of a Form XObject is for content which is used more than once in a page or file, for example a logo on the top of every page. It is defined once, then used multiple times, saving space. It can be used multiple times on the same page by altering the graphics matrix before invoking.

Comment: thanks, I read a bit more about content stream and form xobjects as well as other papers. Is there any known library etc. which allows full automatic extraction of figures as vector files from pdf? until know i just saw approaches which identify the area, where figures might be located within the pdf (and then through rasterization you can get a png etc. of the figure, but not the actual vectors)

Comment: Try https://mupdf.com